# Nearest Region of a Point-cloud

Tags: regions, nearest

For a given examplary set of points `p`(2D)  with known `NearestFunction nf`

```
p={{0.840118, 0.610084}, {0.192507, 0.593158}, {0.924885,0.0381748}, {0.954353, 0.0854852},{0.68415,0.0401017}, {0.930616,0.272383}, {0.53465, 0.248715}, {0.493077, 0.813843}, {0.33337,0.749316},{0.702729, 0.748888}};

nf=Nearest[p];
```

I would like to define a region, which includes all neighbors inside a given range.

```
Graphics[{Lighter[Gray], Map[Disk[#, .25] &, p], Black, Point[p]}]
```

[image]

But

```
cloud=ImplicitRegion[Norm[Nearest[p][{x, y}][[1]] - {x,y}] < .1, {x, y}]
```

gives an error message  `ImplicitRegion::msgs: Evaluation of {Norm[Nearest[p][{x,y}][[1]]-{x,y}]<0.1,True} generated message(s) {NearestFunction::neard}.` which I didn't understand.

Perhaps I have to restrict `x,y` to be `NumericQ` but I have no idea how.

What's wrong with my attempt?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe you can try `cloud = ImplicitRegion[{RegionDistance[Point@p, {x, y}] <= .1}, {x, y}]`?

Comment: @kglr Thanks, that's a tricky workaround!  But I'm still wondering what causes problems with `Nearest`.

Comment: `Nearest` just cannot handle symbolic input because you cannot traverse a space partition tree with a symbolic query point. That's it.

Comment: @HenrikSchuhmacher Thanks, but my question concernes numerical (not symbolical) input to Nearest.

Comment: I would not expect `ImplicitRegion` to handle a black-box function as membership predicate. I doubt it was designed for that.